# How to get route parameter inside the routing module?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing, angular11

How do I get the value of id inside this same routing module ?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'departments/:id',
    component: HrComponent /* (id==='hr')?HrComponent:ITComponent;*/
  }];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DynformRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: path: 'departments/hr and below that the one you have now..

Comment: Unfortunately, Angular does not allow registering a route in that fashion. It would be useful to be able to register a component factory instead of a component